# Сортировка многомерных объектов с учетом иерархии (лексикографическая)

Tags: java, алгоритм, сортировка

Есть массив строк:

```
"M1\RM1\RRM1",
"M2",
"M2\RM1\RRM2",
"M1\RM1",
"M1\RM2\RRM1",
"M2\RM1\RRM1",
"M1\RM2",
"M1\RM1\RRM2",
```

Каждое значение перед и после слэша, там где он есть, это отдел некой фирмы, в которую входит какой-то подотдел. `M1\RM1` означает, что есть отдел `M1`, в который входит подотдел `RM1` и так далее...

Нужен алгоритм который будет сортировать по возрастанию, с учетом иерархии , на пример:

```
"M1\RM1",
"M1\RM1\RRM1",
"M1\RM1\RRM2",
"M1\RM2",
"M1\RM2\RRM1",
"M2",
"M2\RM1\RRM1",
"M2\RM1\RRM2",
```

Помогите пожалуйста уже всю голову сломал, сначала казалось просто, а теперь не как. 
Надо чтобы на JDK 1.7 работало.

Есть такая версия она не правильно работает, но может ее можно поправить:

```
private String[] sortLevel(final Division[] divisions) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this.qSort(divisions, 0, divisions.length - 1, i);
    }

    String[] result = new String[divisions.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < divisions.length; i++) {
        result[i] = divisions[i].div;
    }

    return result;
}

public void qSort(Division[] arr, int low, int high, int key) {
    int i = low;
    int j = high;
    Division x = arr[low+(high-low)/2];
    do {
        while((arr[i].getDivByLevel(key)) < (x.getDivByLevel(key))) ++i;
        while(arr[j].getDivByLevel(key) > x.getDivByLevel(key)) --j;
        if (i <= j) {
            Division temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    } while(i <= j);
    //рекурсивные вызовы функции qSort
    if(low < j) qSort(arr, low, j, key);
    if(i < high) qSort(arr, i, high, key);
}

private class Division {
    final private int K;
    final private int SK;
    final private int SSK;
    final private String div;
    private int length = 0;

    private Division(final String index) {
        this.div = index;
        this.K = getNumberDivision(0, index);
        this.SK = getNumberDivision(1, index);
        this.SSK = getNumberDivision(2, index);
        this.initLength();
    }

    void initLength() {
        if (SSK != -1) this.length++;
        if (SK != -1)  this.length++;
        if (K != -1)   this.length++;
    }

    private int getDivByLevel(final int key) {
        if (key == 2) return SSK;
        if (key == 1) return  SK;
        if (key == 0) return   K;
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    private int getNumberDivision(final int level, final String code) {
        final String[] levels = code.split("\\\\");
        if (level >= levels.length) return -1;
        final String[] numberOfLevel = levels[level].split("[A-Z]");
        return Integer.parseInt(
                numberOfLevel[numberOfLevel.length - 1]
        );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Division{" +
                "K=" + K +
                ", SK=" + SK +
                ", SSK=" + SSK +
                '}';
    }
```

Может зря я затеял на объекты `Division` парсить эти строки, не знаю...

Comment: Да тут по идее обычная сортировка строк должна сработать

Comment: Обычная лексикографическая сортировка... будет работать, пока не появится отдел по имени `M10`.

Comment: @Akina это решаемо. Причем малой кровью.

Comment: @rjhdby Я не зря написАл слово "лексикографическая". Потому что не убеждён, что `по возрастанию` в исполнении автора - это действительно оно...

Comment: @Akina ну если взять приведенные входные и выходные последовательности, то это именно оно. :)

Comment: @Akina спасибо добавил в название вопроса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("M1\\RM1\\RRM1");
    list.add("M2");
    list.add("M2\\RM1\\RRM2");
    list.add("M1\\RM1");
    list.add("M1\\RM2\\RRM1");
    list.add("M2\\RM1\\RRM1");
    list.add("M1\\RM2");
    list.add("M1\\RM1\\RRM2");
    java.util.Collections.sort(list);
    for(String a:list){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Вывод

```
M1\RM1
M1\RM1\RRM1
M1\RM1\RRM2
M1\RM2
M1\RM2\RRM1
M2
M2\RM1\RRM1
M2\RM1\RRM2
```

Правда если у вас появятся индексы больше 9, то придется расставлять костыли. Например предварительно пройтись по списку и заменить регулярками `([^\d])(\d)(\\|$)` на `$10$2$3`, а после сортировки убрать лидирующие нули.

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ кто бы мог подумать что все так просто. Только я не понял как при помощи регулярки решить проблему индексами больше 9. Не могли бы чуть по подробнее расжевать. В чем проблема индексов больше 9 и как регулярки это решает. Спасибо.

Comment: @Павел строки сортируются посимвольно, и если у вас будет две строки `M2` и `M10`, то при стандартной сортировке `M10` будет "меньше" чем `M2`, так как 1<2. Данная регулярка же заменит `M2` на `M02` и, соответственно, эта строка будет "меньше" чем `M10`.